# Windows 8.1 reverts to brand new user profile upon every reboot

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, user-profiles

I'm having a strange problem with a brand new machine that I just installed Windows 8.1 Pro on.  The machine is connected to a domain and I logon with a domain account.

Every time I reboot, the machine *reverts* back to the default user profile.  I lose my wallpaper, I lose any pinned icons I had in the task bar, I lose my Outlook email account settings.  If I start Chrome, it takes me through the guided setup again.  If I start Visual Studio, it says "Please wait while Visual Studio starts for the first time".  Everything in `C:\Users\Mike` is completely wiped away.

I've asked our domain admin and he doesn't believe it's anything on their end.  Has anyone seen this issue, and is there anything that can be done about it?  Thanks!

**Update:**

After some research, I've ruled out the following.  First, I'm not a member of the *Domain Guests* group on the domain controller.  In fact, I'm actually an admin on the domain controller.  Second, there's no `ProfileImagePath` with a `.bak` extension, so it doesn't seem to be some sort of name conflict.

Comment: Honestly.  This sound like something on their end.  So you are a domain Administrator?  Do you end up after the profile is created with a local Administrator or User?  While being a local Administrator often means nothing being a domain Administrator and being a local User could cause some wierd conflicts.

Comment: Do you use roaming profiles? Could be that you don't have full access to your server side profile folder and therefore can't upload any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your group policy editor. Under system settings, there is a login option "always use local profiles". Ensure that's enabled.